# INSERT conflict with Foreign Key constraint using ID generated by separate script

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've been getting this error (with table names changed):

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__SubTable__Table__xxxxxxxx". The conflict occurred in database "Development", table "dbo.Table", column 'TableID'.

From essentially this script (being called as a procedure)

```
begin

    begin transaction

    begin try

        declare @TableID int

        exec @TableID = createParent    @params... = [params...]


        insert into [dbo].[SubTable]
            (
            [TableID]
            ,[other fields...]
            )
        select
            @TableID
            ,[other params..]

        select
            SCOPE_IDENTITY()    [SubTableID]
            ,@TableID           [TableID];

    end try
    begin catch
        select
            ERROR_NUMBER()
            ,ERROR_NUMBER()
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY()
            ,ERROR_STATE()
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
            ,ERROR_LINE()
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE()

        select @Commit = 0;

    end catch

    if @Commit = 1
    begin
        commit transaction
    end

    if @Commit = 0
    begin
        rollback transaction
    end

end
```

The `createParent` script works very similarly except it's not calling any other scripts and only selects it's own `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Anyone know or understand what the issue here is? (Or can suggest an alternative method for creating a record in another table, preferably using the other stored proc and using its ID as a foreign key)

Edit:

Managed to get it working, if anyone else happens to be in the same situation; inserting the result of the procedure into a table variable rather than a scalar variable and then selecting out from that solves the issue for me.

Comment: Looks like the table `SubTable` has a unique key that your stored proc is attempting to violate, i.e. your data has duplicate sets of key values for that index.

Comment: The problem probably exists in the `createParent` script.  Apparently it's not returning a valid value to the `@TableID` variable.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thing is I get _AN_ ID, but now that I check no record corresponds to it.

Comment: So the problem IS in `createParent`, which is code you haven't shown us, so we can't help you with it until you do.

Answer (score 1):

Although technically possible, returning a value from a stored procedure (other than an execution status) is a bad habit. Instead, you should be using an output parameter.

I am thinking the code should look more like this:

```
declare @TableID int;
declare @status int;

exec @status = createParent    @params... = [params...], @TableId output;
```

Then you would check `@status` to see if it is correct.

In your case, you are probably returning a bad id. I might suspect that an `if` with one of the following conditions would work:

```
if @TableId is not null
begin
. . .
end;
```

Or:

```
if @TableId > 0
. . .
```

At the very least, this should work:

```
if exists (select 1 from <tabletable> t where t.TableId = @tableId)
. . .
```